# Kivy Button: on_press function called before its being pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Im writing a Sudoku solver UI in Kivy.
I wanted to add a button, which upon being pressed, solves the Grid. The function works, although when I assign it to a button as the on_press function, it somehow runs before the button is pressed. I've tried everything. I get an **Assertion Error**. When I just use the solve function, it works. Not with the button, though.

Thank you for helping.

**This is the __init__ function:**

```
class SudokuGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(SudokuGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.grid = [[8,7,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0],
        [0,0,0, 9,0,0, 0,0,4],
        [0,2,0, 7,0,0, 1,0,5],
        [0,0,9, 6,0,0, 0,3,0],
        [0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,9],
        [0,0,6, 5,4,0, 0,0,0],
        [6,9,0, 0,0,0, 7,0,0],
        [2,0,0, 0,0,7, 4,0,0],
        [0,0,0, 3,0,0, 0,1,0]]

        self.add_widget(Button(on_press=self.solve()))

        self.cols = 3
        self.rows = 4
        self.load_grid()
```

**And this my solve function:**

```
def solve(self):
        for x in range(9):
            for y in range(9):
                if self.grid[y][x] == 0:
                    for n in range(1,10):
                        if self.possible(y,x,n):
                            self.grid[y][x] = n
                            self.solve()
                            self.grid[y][x] = 0
                    return
        self.load_grid()
        print(np.matrix(self.grid))
```

I know that the function is run, because before the App terminates, I get the output of the solved Grid.

This is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\victo\Desktop\portfolio\Sudoku\sudoku_app.py", line 217, in <module>
     sudoku_game.run()
   File "C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:\Users\victo\Desktop\portfolio\Sudoku\sudoku_app.py", line 205, in build
     self.sudoku_grid = SudokuGrid()
   File "C:\Users\victo\Desktop\portfolio\Sudoku\sudoku_app.py", line 73, in __init__
     self.add_widget(Button(on_press=self.solve()))
   File "C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 121, in __init__
     super(ButtonBehavior, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\label.py", line 318, in __init__
     super(Label, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 369, in __init__
     self.bind(**on_args)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 419, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind
 AssertionError: None is not callable
```

Comment: You want to pass the name of the function to call, not actually call the function, when you make the button. Try `on_press=self.solve` instead of `on_press=self.solve()`

Comment: When I try that, I also get an error: solve takes 1 positional arguments but 2 were given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i figured it out. Erik said in his comment:

> Try `on_press=self.solve` in stead of `on_press=self.solve()`

which worked, although I got another Error. I had one too many positional arguments for solve(). I fixed it by defining my method as:

```
def solve(self, *args)
```

Everything works now.